# Где располагать директорию GIT для Drupal 8?

Tags: git, drupal, drupal8, drupal7

Установил ядро Drupal 8 через composer.

В корневой папке Drupal располагается директория GIT.

Для своего проекта, использовать эту директорию? или в папке WEB инициализировать директорию и использовать её для разработки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В корневой папке Drupal располагается директория GIT. Для своего проекта, использовать эту директорию?

Да, это стандартная практика.

> или в папке WEB инициализировать директорию и использовать её для разработки?

Не стоит т.к. в репозиторий не попадёт много важного, например composer.json.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, все зависит от твоих нужд. Но обычно да, где index php, там там и инициализируй git. https://github.com/github/gitignore тут если что есть пример игнора для d7

https://github.com/wearewondrous/drupal-8-best-practices/blob/master/.gitignore d8